# Modify bounding box of GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, extents, geopandas, rasterio

I have a GeoDataFrame which is a multipolygon and represents boundaries of a country:

`0    MULTIPOLYGON (((10.10112 46.23346, 10.10099 46...`

Its bounding box/extent is:

`minx       miny      maxx       maxy
5.956063  45.817059  10.495112  47.808483`

I would like to extend the bounding box using a parameter let's say `ext = 1.4` so it will become:

`minx       miny      maxx       maxy
8.338488  64.143881  14.693157  66.931876`

I'm trying to extend it so when I display the raster, the layer is not cropped too tightly and I don't lose some of the information around it. When I try 
`data.bounds *= 1.4`,
I get the following error:
`AttributeError: can't set attribute`. It seems like I can't modify the DataFrame directly. What's the proper way of extending the bounding box of a GeoDataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a one-row geodataframe, using bounds is okay but ideally, you'd use `total_bounds` to get the bounds of the geodataframe as a whole. This returns a tuple of 4 coordinates ([documentation](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds)). I recommend this approach:

- Get the bounds by using `gdf.total_bounds`:

```
bounds = gdf.total_bounds
```

- Use `shapely` (underlying objects that are used in a geodataframe)

```
from shapely.geometry import box
country_box = box(*bounds)
```

- This `country_box` is now a shapely geometry that can now be modified.

```
buffered_box = country_box.buffer(1.4) # Be careful about the units you use. 1.4 in decimal degrees can be a lot!
```

- You can then use this geometry towards creating another geodataframe/writing to a file/just look at the wkt (`buffered_box.wkt` for example)